# Fetching data from the server to Backbone giving me a weird json

Tags: backbone.js, fetch, json

I'm trying to fetching data from the server with backbone, this is my request:

I initialize the view with this:

```
// Backbone view initialize
this.collection = new Dropdown.Collections.Brands();
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
```

I send the data to my server from my Backbone View:

```
// after the input text fires keypress event
this.collection.fetch({data: {limit: 10, term:value}, reset: true});
```

I response this from PHP:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

This is what's inside the response:

```
"{\"brands\":{\"0\":{\"type\":\"brand\",\"id\":\"3\",\"text\":\"Smith\",\"manufacturer\":{\"text\":\"Proctor\",\"id\":\"1\"},\"image\":null}}}"
```

In the `render` function i log this to see what I get:

```
console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
```

This is the Chrome debugger that gives me this:

[image]

I'm not sure where is the error, I've tried different working ways by skipping the `fetch` method and using a `jquery plugin handler` for the input text, but i would do it with the right way, where is the problem?

Also `Response Headers` are the same for both methods.

I've solved the problem by overriding the `parse` method of the `collection`:

```
parse:function (response) {
    return jQuery.parseJSON(response);
}
```

With that it works, but shouldn't it works correctly by default?

Comment: Maybe try to add a header to your response. At the moment `response` in your `parse` method contains a string (that explains the result of your log as a string is more or less like an array), which is pretty abnormal (it's already been parsed here). Also check the network tab to see what could be wrong (in the response).

Answer (score 0):

Lol the problem was a `json_ecode` called twice in different places, now everything works perfect.